# How to save textarea content as a post title

Tags: wordpress, textarea

I have a textarea instead of an input field in edit post screen, and i want to save textarea content as a post_title, but i dont know how to extract the data. How?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_insert_post_data()` filter for changing post_title dynamically.

reference :- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/

Try Out this code :-
replace `textarea_field` with your textarea name.

```
function zillion_filter_post_title( $data, $postarr, $unsanitized_postarr){
    $data['post_title'] = $_POST['textarea_field'];
    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'zillion_filter_post_title',10,3);
```